# Regression for consumer purchase behavior using R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm pursuing a project as part of my MBA and while I have some basic stats background I am very new to in-depth regression analysis. I'm looking to use R for my analysis in order to learn a new tool. I'm very new to R, so the more detail you would be willing to provide the better.

Here's a description of the data I'm working with. I do have more granular data if I should transform this somehow. The data describes consumers' choices for buying a product (or not) - so my binary outcome is purchase / not purchase. They buy a product (say product X), but in the process look at products A, B, C and X. I would like to attribute value for the purchase of X to products A, B, and C based on their contribution to the likelihood of selling X.

What becomes difficult is there are a variable number of products viewed prior to the purchase, really 1 --> n products. The timing of each may also be a factor. If a consumer reviews products today and buys today that may be different than reviewing products 2 weeks prior to purchasing. I have accurate timing information with each product as well.

My question is: how can I construct a regression model to consider a dynamic number of independent variables for the same consumer?

Please let me know if I haven't been specific enough.

Thank you!

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you provide a representative sample of your data, or a link to the full dataset.

Comment: Here's an abbreviated example along with some comments and an example of the desired output from the model.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArQm8_RUtcICdE9wQlBFTWZfQkxXckFTeTJKaDZEVmc&usp=sharing#gid=0[/link]

Answer (score 0):

You could specify all the independents' names in a vector:

```
x <- c("A","B","C")
```

the dependent into y:

```
y <- "X"
```

and then construct a formula that you can pass to `lm`:

```
> model <- as.formula(paste(y,paste(x,collapse="+"), sep="~"))
> model
X ~ A + B + C
```

By simply modifying your x vector and re-running this, it'll take into account an arbitrary number of independents. If you then put this into a function, all you have to do is pass the vector of independents to it and it'll return to you the model:

```
createModel <- function(x) {
   model <- as.formula(paste(y,paste(x,collapse="+"), sep="~"))
   return(model)
}
```

which when you run you get:

```
> createModel(c("A","B"))
X ~ A + B
> createModel(c("A","B","D","E"))
X ~ A + B + D + E
```

Assuming you've already specified y of course. You could add it as a parameter to the function as well, if you wanted to. Hopefully that's roughly what you want.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  In my example data I've simplified the products to A, B, C... however in reality there are thousands (or more) products and combinations of products.  How might I generalize the creation of the x vector?